# How can constants of a specific type be defined?

Tags: typescript, union, constants

How can I define nullary value constructors aka constants of a specific type:

```
interface True {tag: "True"};
interface False {tag: "False"};

type Bool = True | False;

const a = {tag: "True"}; // managed only that
const a = True; // desired
```

Comment: Do you want to have `const a = True` in TS and it emits `const a = {tag: "True"};` as JavaScript?

Comment: Generally speaking, the static type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when TS is compiled to JS, so the interface `True` will not exist at runtime.  You could define `function True(): True { return { tag: "True" } }` and then write `const a = True();`.  Or you could replace your interface with `class True { readonly tag = "True" }` and then write `const a = new True();`.  That's the closest I can imagine getting. Does either of those work for you? I can write up an answer unless you have an outstanding question.

Comment: Are you maybe asking about [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)?

Comment: @VLAZ No, I want `True` to be a constant value of type `Bool`.

Comment: @jcalz _the static type system is erased_ - that's why I used the term value constructor as opposed to type constructor. So TS can only define explicit nullary value constructors like `function True(): True { return { tag: "True" } }`. Thanks!

Comment: @GiacomoDeLiberali No, I have a discriminated union with nullary value constructors in mind. That isn't an enum I think. So you are from Pisa? Hang in there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an interface maybe you could use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). See the [playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgO6oHSQJ4wKZwMYBOAljJADYCGAdgOZoD2htwAJg-nMODawEYMGAa2CEc5HJTg4AtNQaQ8wLLgIkyMgMwyALGigBbcgGJ8DanEgyp0wpGLm4AKCdmLkUABVCAVxygAXlAAb1BISloEUAAibz9o0ABfUClQN0tXRw8AMUpyaUCQ8MiY3PycaOTU9MgAbhcVfwAhQXJCxoYAMy9ffwAfMOwcLtAy6XrM9xTCuJwJ9IYJNHIGWgAKaIBBaIAaSgBKUBAiiKjY3sqgA)

```js
const True = { tag: "True" } as const
const False = { tag: "False" } as const;

type Bool = typeof True | typeof False; // type Bool = { readonly tag:"True";} | { readonly tag: "False"; }

const a = True;

console.log(a) // { tag: "True" }
```

Comment: Looks good. I am not very familiar with TS though. Is this considered a hack?

Comment: I wouldn’t consider this as an hack, but it’s a strange use case